# MS Word encoding (after conversion)

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, encoding

I have a couple of MS Word docs I want to clean up but don't know what all the encoding means. I'm wondering if there's a list somewhere so I don't have to copy and paste every example.

Here's some of the problem:

`åThis åis åthe France of åwinding åmountainðroads, ååsmall åcottages åwith åred åbrick-tile åroofs, åandðhillside ågardens.  åThe åview åfrom the åtrain åincludes åaðcathedral åwith proportions and general characteristics thatðmatch åthe åone åin Cologne, åalthough its åactual åsize åisðproportional åto`

This is in Word ('97), but I'm pretty sure it's either a conversion from an earlier version of Word, or possibly a conversion from a very early database program from the 90s.

I've figured out some of the encoding from the context (already fixed/removed):

- ä is a space
- ï is a line break

but there are several others that I can't figure out, like the ones in the example above (å, ð, etc.), and `ñ`, and a square (that can't be copied here.) Some I could probably just delete, but I'd rather know what the symbols mean, just in case.

Does anyone know of a list of replacement styles or formatting that would apply to these characters?

Comment: If you can open the doc with free LibreOffice *Writer*, just save as text or remove  formatting.

Comment: I'd rather know what the symbols mean so I can replace them with the correct/original formatting.

Comment: Another example (squares auto-removed when I pasted here): `Ð $  ñ ñ Flightñ `.

Comment: I've been using Word since Word 95 and have never seen these in a Word document. This looks like text pasted from the web or converted from another file format. I do not currently have Word 97. Try saving a sample with this on a cloud site like DropBox or OneDrive and adding a link to it in your question.

Comment: It's not from the web. They're my files I've had since forever and as I said, something happened during a conversion (or something similar), possibly from another program. It's happened before to other files of mine. I can't remember their origin. Possibly a db program called smartii. Files have personal stuff in them so I can't post publicly more than I have.